# How to post a scope variable right after it has changed the value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angularjs and want to use $http.post() method. 
In HTML
    
In Javascript

```
$scope.onevariable ='value1'
  $scope.doSomething = function(){
     $scope.onevariable = 'value2'; 
     $http.post('someurl',{onevariable:$scope.onevariable }).then(function(){...})}
```

The problem is that I want to post the changed $scope.onevariable as parameter to the server, and this variable has to be changed after I click the button. However,this $scope.onevariable can be posted before it has changed to 'value2', so how can I post it exactly after the value has been changed. 'value2' is unknown value to me,or an encrypted string, you can treat it as a random string.

Comment: Bind `ng-change` event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $watch would be an option

```
$scope.$watch('onevariable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $http.post('someurl',{onevariable:newValue }).then(function(){...})}
});
```

[More about $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope/#$watch)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know if I understand your question well, but here's is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.onevariable ='';
  $scope.post = false;
  var increment = 0;

  $scope.changeVar = function() {
    $scope.onevariable = 'value' + ++increment;
  }

  $scope.$watch('onevariable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue && newValue == 'value2') {
       doPost();
    }
  });

  function doPost () {
    // post
    $scope.post = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="changeVar()">Click me</button>
  <hr ng-if="onevariable" />
  <code ng-bind="onevariable"></code>
  <hr />
  <code ng-bind="'Post? ' + post"></code>
</body>

</html>
```